# MySQL distinct in 2 rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select, distinct

I got something like this database structure:

```
2017 | February
2017 | February
2018 | February
2019 | February
```

Output should be:

```
2017 | February
2018 | February 
2019 | February
```

Is it possible to get this to work with an distinct argument?

Comment: I think you knew about this but haven't tried.

Comment: @detective404 Yes of course I knew about it and also tried it but it still wont work

Comment: I am not good in SO but I suggest always add your `try` `tried code`,`tried query` to get good attention

Comment: 1) How about giving it a try? 2) Yeah put distinct there in the correct position in the current query that you were too lazy show. 3) Using DISTINCT is often a crutch for a badly written query and typically hides a logic error at the cost of performance. ... Of course if you had bothered to show: a) your query, b) your table structures, c) sample data for your tables. ... You might be able to get advice on how to solve your problem _without_ DISTINCT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to using `DISTINCT` would be to use `GROUP BY` and do an aggregation:

```
SELECT year, month
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY year, month
```

From the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html) we find that `DISTINCT` is often implemented internally using `GROUP BY`:

> In most cases, a DISTINCT clause can be considered as a special case of GROUP BY.

Most of the time, `GROUP BY` would be preferable because it allows us to use aggregate functions while `DISTINCT` does not.

Answer (score 2):

Just apply the `distinct` modifier to your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `year`, `month`
FROM   mytable
```

Comment: also possible by `GROUP BY year`

Comment: @detective404 Technically speaking, whoever posted later should delete his answer.  It is rare that two people post at exactly the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just do:

```
select distinct year, month
  from your_table
```

Comment: not part of question but SO, what comes in mind if somebody comes simultaneously with same answers.